# Why verbs are singular for past and future tense?

Tags: grammar

I am curious why there is no plural for past/future tense.

i.e

present tense - He hurts himself while cutting the fruits.

past tense - He hurt himself while cutting the fruits.

future tense - He might hurt himself while cutting the fruits.

Comment: The only plural in any of those sentences, "fruits," is plural in all three tenses, so . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying that "verbs are singular for past and future tense" or "there is no plural for past/future tense" is a very awkward, unintuitive way of putting this. The verb form in English for second person never conjugates for number, but I would not say that "you all are" uses a singular verb with a plural meaning.

I would say instead that the singular and plural forms are identical for verbs in the past and future tense, or in the second person; another way to think of it is that there is no singular/plural distinction at all for verb forms in these categories.

In fact, though, there is one verb that has separate singular and plural past-tense forms: "to be," which has *I, he, she, it **was*** but *we, you, they **were.***

As for "why"... it's just how the various forms have evolved. Historically, a lot of suffixes have been lost from English words, which caused a lot of inflectional forms that were once distinct to fall together in the modern language.

The future tense example is actually not an isolated occurrence; the verb *will* falls into the more general category of "[modal auxiliaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs)," which all lack inflection for number. Other modal verbs are *would, can, could, shall, should, must.*

Answer (score 1):

*Hurts* is third person *singular* present simple. The form is *hurt* for all other persons and number in this tense. This is the only person that has a different form. This applies to using *has* rather than *have* in such third person singular conjugations as  present perfect (*He has hurt*), present perfect continuous (*He has been hurting himself*).

Other than that, only the verb *to be* has different forms. In the past tense, there is only the choice of *was* and *were* depending on person and mood.

There is no future tense conjugation in English. We have different ways of taking about future time. These include using modals (usually *will*) and  *to be going to*. The latter conjugates just like *to be*, so *they are going to hurt themselves* is a third person plural construction that refers to future time. Modal verbs such as *will* and *might* do not change forms for person or number.